# How i can install telegram-mtproto on Ubuntu 20.04 CLI?

Tags: node.js, client, telegram, mtproto

I want to install telegram-mtproto by tyhe following command on Ubuntu 20.04 CLI. npm install --save

`npm install --save telegram-mtproto@beta`

but when i execute the command i gain the following errors !

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/MTProxy/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/MTProxy/package.json'
npm WARN worker-loader@0.8.1 requires a peer of webpack@>=0.9 <2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN MTProxy No description
npm WARN MTProxy No repository field.
npm WARN MTProxy No README data
npm WARN MTProxy No license field.

+ telegram-mtproto@2.2.2
updated 1 package and audited 61 packages in 1.472s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 2 moderate severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

can anybody help me to install telegram-mtproto and run a simple node.js client script ?
best regards : mehdi